# I am unable to add custom fields to Serenity Reports (using the latest version)

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, thucydides

I am trying to add Custom Fields to Serenity report mentioned in this link: 
https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/extended-reports.html

Tried by adding `ApplicationVersion` information in serenity properties file in this format :

```
report.customfields.ApplicationVersion = 1.2.3
```

The serenity version that I use is **2.0.17**.

I have tried with

```
mvn serenity:aggregate -DHOST=$HOST -Dreport.customfields.ApplicationVersion=1.2.4
```

command as well, but in vain.

Can you please let me know the way to fix this?

Comment: You can file a bug here https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-maven-plugin/issues